# Cmd+Space shortcut isn't passed to the Parallels Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts, parallels

I created a virtual machine of Xubuntu 18.04 on Parallels Desktop 14.0.1 (45154). Immediately after the installation it was necessary to install Parallels Tools and there were problems with this. I used [this](https://bartsimons.me/installing-parallels-tools-on-ubuntu-18-04/) instruction. It works perfectly.

But now I want to switch the language using the native `Cmd + Space` keyboard shortcut. To do this I create a rule in Parallels Desktop:
[image]
Shortcuts like `Cmd + A`, `Cmd + S`, `Cmd + V` and etc, works fine.

In the Xubuntu set the keyboard shortcut to switch the language `Ctrl + Shift`:
[image]

And shortcut `Cmd + Space` doesn't work. `Cmd + Shift` or `Control + Shift` works fine. But not `Cmd + Space`.

I suppose this problem arises because Parallels does not have time to intercept the keyboard shortcut, because macOS intercepts it itself and change language in macOS. But this keyboard shortcut works in a Windows virtual machine.

I hope you will forgive me for my screenshots of the interface in Russian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue with a Windows virtual machine. You should disable keyboard layout synchronization between your OS and the virtual machine.

All that you need is to find and modify config.pvs file.

```
<KeyboardLayoutSync dyn_lists="">
   <Enabled>1</Enabled>
```

And change 1 to 0. It should look like this:

```
<KeyboardLayoutSync dyn_lists="">
    <Enabled>0</Enabled>
```

This [answer](https://kb.parallels.com/115200) helped me.